# Is *Tako to Ama* obscene pornography?

Tags: united-states, california, pornography

*Tako to Ama*, better known as [*the dream of the fisherman's wife*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dream_of_the_Fisherman%27s_Wife) or *pearl diver and two octopi*, is an 1814 woodblook print by Housukai. It is widely reprinted from its original source for artistic purposes, often cropped. However, the problem is not that it is *art* it is in part its history, and content matter.

- It was originally part of a dedicated erotica book called *Kinoe no Komatsu* ('Young Pines') and accompanied by an erotic tale.
- It depicts oral intercourse of a nude female with two octopi.

This makes me wonder: Does this work get the treatment of an **artistic** nude or **obscene** pornography in the US (or for more specific: California), or does this depend on how the picture is framed?

Comment: Why does it matter?pornography is not illegal in the US?

Comment: @DaleM the handling of such in front of minors however is

Comment: Some pornography is illegal in the United States.

Comment: Apparently it was featured on-screen in an episode of *Mad Men*, and presumably AMC's lawyers know what is and isn't illegal obscenity.

Comment: "does this depend on how the picture is framed" I don't see how what frame you put it in would be relevant, unless there's further pornography on the frame.

Comment: framing of a picture is also the term for things like *embedded in text* or what is *surrounding* the picture - e.g. is the picture in a translated text of the original text or just on a bare wall, or is it surrounded by adult toys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are federal laws against distributing [*obscene* material to minors](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1470), or producing or possessing *obscene* [material depicting minors](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1466A). Other prohibitions against *obscene* material  include mailing it (§1461), importing it (§1462) and producing it (§1465).
[Here](https://www.justice.gov/criminal-ceos/citizens-guide-us-federal-law-obscenity) is the DoJ guideline on laws restricting *obscene* material. As developed in  Miller v. California, 413 U.S. 15, Smith v. US, 431 U.S. 291, and Pope v. Illinois, 481 U.S. 497, there is a three-pronged test

> Whether the average person, applying contemporary adult community
> standards, finds that the matter, taken as a whole, appeals to
> prurient interests (i.e., an erotic, lascivious, abnormal, unhealthy,
> degrading, shameful, or morbid interest in nudity, sex, or excretion);
>
> Whether the average person, applying contemporary adult community
> standards, finds that the matter depicts or describes sexual conduct
> in a patently offensive way (i.e., ultimate sexual acts, normal or
> perverted, actual or simulated, masturbation, excretory functions,
> lewd exhibition of the genitals, or sado-masochistic sexual abuse);
>
> Whether a reasonable person finds that the matter, taken as a whole,
> lacks serious literary, artistic, political, or scientific value.

There is no prohibition against pornographic material, so we needn't be concerned with whether the material is pornographic, the pertinent question is whether it is **obscene**. This has to be determined by consulting "the average person, applying contemporary adult community
standards" and whether a "reasonable" person will find that it
lacks serious literary, artistic, political, or scientific value. This can only be determined at trial.

Comment: You come to the conclusion that the question is "is it obscene" which is the very question...

Comment: The question confuses the issue by introducing the legally irrelevant concept of "pornography", a confusion which infects the discussion.

Comment: For your sake, I highlighted the operative distinction of the question: artistic or Obscene?!

Comment: @Trish You're asking for a legal answer to a factual question.  I would never find that a particular work contains no serious artistic merit.  Other jurors may disagree with that factual finding, but both of us are finding facts based on the law provided in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the work is obviously pornographic, but it seems equally clear that it has serious historical and artistic value -- even to a juvenile -- so it would not be considered obscenity and would remain generally protected under the First Amendment.